# How to close AlertDialog with keyboard Enter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, dismiss

Currently when i enter text in the editText field and hit enter on the keyboard it changes my text as intended but the AlertDialog stays on screen as well as the keyboard. Is there a way i can close the Alert and keyboard when i hit enter? `alertDialog.dismiss()` or `alertDialog.close()` does not work for me. Thanks for your time.

```
(1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        tv.setOnLongClickListener {

            //Alert Window
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            alertDialog.setTitle("NEW PRICE")
            val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
            //Alert Submit on Enter
            input.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // Input changes text
                    tv.text = input.text
                    when {
                        tv.text.startsWith("-") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                        tv.text.startsWith("+") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                    else -> {
                        tv.text = "_"
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                    }
                    }
                    // Close Alert Window
                    alertDialog.dismiss()


                    // Save Price Table
                }
                false
            }


            val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            input.layoutParams = lp
            alertDialog.setView(input).show()
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `alertDialog.dismiss()` compile?

Comment: no it doesnt compile i just left it in there for the example.

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: again thank you very much @forpas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `alertDialog` as `AlertDialog.Builder` and not `AlertDialog`.  
There is no `dismiss()` method for `AlertDialog.Builder`.  
Change:

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
```

to

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()
```

and

```
alertDialog.setView(input).show()
```

to

```
alertDialog.setView(input)
alertDialog.show()
```